# How to count occurence of true positives using pandas or numpy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two columns, Prediction and Ground Truth.
I want to get a count of true positives as a series using either numpy or pandas.

For example, my data is:

```
Prediction GroundTruth
True       True
True       False
True       True
False      True
False      False
True       True
```

I want a list that should have the following output:

```
tp_list = [1,1,2,2,2,3]
```

Is there a one-liner way to do this in numpy or pandas?

Currently, this is my solution:

```
tp = 0
for p, g in zip(data.Prediction, data.GroundTruth):
  if p and g: # TP case
    tp = tp + 1
  tp_list.append(tp)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a running count (i.e., cumulative sum) of *true positives*, i.e., `Prediction == True` if and only if `GroundTruth == True`, the solution is a modification of @RafaelC's answer:

```
(df['Prediction'] & df['GroundTruth']).cumsum()
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    2
5    3

(df['Prediction'] & df['GroundTruth']).cumsum().tolist()
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to know how many `True` you predicted that are actually `True`, use

```
(df['Prediction'] & df['GroundTruth']).cumsum()

0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    2
5    3
dtype: int64
```

(thanks @Peter Leimbigiler for chiming in)

If you want to know how many you have predicted correctly just compare and use `cumsum`

```
(df['Prediction'] == df['GroundTruth']).cumsum()
```

which outputs

```
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    3
5    4
dtype: int64
```

Can always get a list by using `.tolist()`

```
(df4['Prediction'] == df4['GroundTruth']).cumsum().tolist()

[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: `df['Prediction'] == df['GroundTruth']` gives true positives _plus_ true negatives, basically the accuracy score before dividing by the number of predictions. The running count of _true positives_ is given by `df['Prediction'] & df['GroundTruth']`.

Comment: if the ground truth is `False` and the prediction is `False`, what do you call this outcome? The predictor correctly classified a negative instance. It's a true negative.

Comment: @RafaelC, the distinction between "correct prediction" and "correct prediction *of a negative outcome*" is important :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix

Comment: Thanks a ton guys! you are too fast. I posted this question right before boarding a flight and I had an answer after boarding!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can using `all`

```
df.all(1).cumsum().tolist()
Out[156]: [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
```

`numpy` solution

```
np.cumsum(np.all(df.values,1))
Out[159]: array([1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3], dtype=int32)
```